# Can't see my widget in frame in tkinter. I want to see button in bottom of the frame in on ceneter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't see my buttons.

I want to get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQMnl.png)

I want to see button in bottom of the frame in on ceneter.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x650+0+0')
root.title("SV Configuration")
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

frame_btn = Frame(root)
frame_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="nswe")
frame_center = Frame(frame_btn)
frame_center.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
ok_btn = Button(frame_center, text="Ok")
cancel_btn = Button(frame_center, text="Cancel")
cancel_btn.pack()
ok_btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the size of `frame_btn` will be 1x1 because its only child `frame_center` is put inside the frame using `.place()` which does not adjust its size automatically.

You need to use `root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)` and `root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` (as `frame_center` is put at row 4 and column 1) to let `frame_center` to fill the available space of `frame_btn`.

Second, the two buttons are put inside `frame_center` using `.pack()` so they will be by default packing vertically, not what you want them to be horizontally.  So specify `side=LEFT` on both `.pack()` to pack them horizontally.  Also it is better to specify the `width` and `height` options of the two buttons so that they have same size.

Third, the `frame_center` is put at the center of `frame_btn` because `.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)`. To put it at the bottom, use `.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=S)` instead.

Finally, you have imported `tkinter` twice:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

wildcard import is not recommended, so remove `from tkinter import *` and add prefix `tk.` to widget classes, like `tk.Button`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x650+0+0')
root.title("SV Configuration")
#root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame_btn = tk.Frame(root)
frame_btn.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="nswe")

frame_center = tk.Frame(frame_btn)
frame_center.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor=tk.S)

ok_btn = tk.Button(frame_center, text="Ok", width=20, height=3)
cancel_btn = tk.Button(frame_center, text="Cancel", width=20, height=3)

cancel_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
ok_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Why rely=0.9 ? How did you calculate it ? @acw1668

Comment: It is just an example, you can use another value to suit your requirement.

Comment: Or you can use `frame_center.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, pady=20)` instead of `.place()`.  Change `pady` to any value that you want.